# How to pass authentication token with every React request to back end API?

Tags: reactjs

I have an existing application in which REST APIs are already developed. I am thinking to develop a front end using React JS and front end should call my REST APIs with every request.

However when I login to my application then a token is generated which is passed to every subsequent requests as an authentication header. How can I achieve this using React?
I am a beginner in React.

Comment: How do you communicate with the API from you React code?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `axios` as a library, and add this as a configuration

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 1):

Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Example:

```
var data = {myData: 'hello'}; // or just 'hello'

fetch(YOUR_URL, {
  method: 'POST', // or GET
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be string or object
  headers:{
    'Authorization': YOUR_TOKEN,
    // ... add other header lines like: 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json()) // if response is json, for text use res.text()
.then(response => console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(response))) // if text, no need for JSON.stringify
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

First receive the token and save it to your browsers local storage using `localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));`

Then, everytime you send a request, you get this token from your local storage using `localStorage.getItem("token")`

Thereafter, if you were POSTing an object with a key value of ID: 1, you would do:

```
await fetch("your_API_endpoint", {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")  },
                            body: JSON.stringify({'ID': '1'})
                        })
```